# Searching for Text in Textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

I'm trying to write a script that searches some text pasted in a text area and highlights whether the setting is correct or incorrect.

The text would be like this:

```
Setting A: Yes
Setting B: No
Setting C: Yes
```

If 'Setting A' should be 'No' then I need that line of text highlighting red. If it is 'No' then hightlight the line green. Same for the other lines.

Where I've got to: http://jsfiddle.net/Mobius1/Hw5cn/6/

**EDIT:** Made slight progress, but it seems a very long-winded way of doing it: http://jsfiddle.net/Mobius1/Hw5cn/8/

Comment: So you want to apply different css color attributes to just a *part* of the value of `<textarea>`?

Comment: Correct. If 'Setting A' should be 'No' then I need that line highlighting red if it's 'Yes'. If 'Setting A' is already 'No' then highlight that line green. If you know what I mean.

Comment: Since the lines of text are in a single tag (the `<textarea>` tag), any css applied will affect the entire tag. To have css settings that are different for different texts, you'll need to separate the texts into different tags.

Comment: does it have to all go in a single `textarea`? Perhaps you could break it out into multiple text boxes. Or show the analysis right below the textarea.

Comment: I've edited the OP with my progress. Seems long-winded though.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hw5cn/9/ The `g` means global search so it will replace all instances of each word.

Comment: @sachleen - yours and stevether's answer are what I'm looking for, thanks! Jonathan M - thanks for the suggestion of analyzing it in another div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this get you any closer?

```
var lines = $("#text").val().split("\n");

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

   $('#output')
       .append(
           $("<span>" + lines[i] + "</span><br />")
               .addClass(lines[i].indexOf('No') != -1 ? 'bad' : 'good')
       );
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/imoda/Hw5cn/11/